# What is the different between Mobile Native Dynamic Maps and Dynamic Maps

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

Google just announced a new pricing plan for Google Maps APIs which will go into effect on 11 June 2018, however, What is the different between Mobile Native Dynamic Maps and Dynamic Maps. How do I know which maps I am using ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of a service and not about coding.

Answer (score 7):

A Dynamic map is a map where you can place markers and infowindows that dynamically change, like for instance when you pan, zoom in, zoom out, etc.

The only difference is that Mobile Native Dynamic Map they mean for Android and IOS (SDKs) and the normal Dynamic Map for Javascript API.

Comment: Thanks betofarina